# Why does bound events get called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jstree in my page in order to manage the display of a tree.
I have attached events for the creation, rename... of branch in my tree.
The problem is that events are sometimes called 2,3,4 times and I want only one.
My tree has 3 new branch in place of 1 (because create is called 3 times in place of 1). I have the same case with all my action, the ajax function is called several times.

Edit : I have found why but don't know how to correct it. My tree is in a jquery pop-up. When I quit the pop up my tree is destroyed and created again when I return in the pop up. When I open the pop up for the second times it create 2 branches, 3 times => 3 branches...
I delete my tree like this, i don't know if it's the good way

```
$("#tree").empty();
$("#tree").removeClass();
$("#tree").removeAttr("role");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the function jstree().destroy(); in the documentation.
This function does what I need. It's ok now. Hope it can help others